# html2canvas google map zoom-in

Tags: google-maps, canvas, zooming

I have a div that display the vehicle travel using google map ip v3. Im using html2canvas `http://html2canvas.hertzen.com`. Its work fine but if you zoom-in the map it fail

```
html2canvas: Renderer: Canvas renderer done - returning canvas obj
html2canvas: Preload starts: finding background-images
html2canvas: Preload: Finding images
html2canvas: Preload: Done.
html2canvas: start: images: 1 / 35 (failed: 0)
html2canvas: start: images: 2 / 35 (failed: 0)
.
.
html2canvas: start: images: 30 / 35 (failed: 0)
html2canvas: start: images: 31 / 35 (failed: 0)
```

or some times this is what happen. (Sorry my reputation is less than ten so i cant upload picture)

Zoom-in (print screen from browser)

http://i1207.photobucket.com/albums/bb480/zerodel_01/zoom2.jpg

Output of html2canvas

http://i1207.photobucket.com/albums/bb480/zerodel_01/download4.png

here is my code:

```
function printme(){
    html2canvas($('#maincontent'), {
        proxy: "server.js",
        useCORS: true,
        logging: true,
  onrendered: function(canvas) {
    var imgString = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
      var mywindow = window.open('', 'my div', 'height=400,width=600');
        mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>my div</title>');
   href="main.css" type="text/css" />');
        mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
        mywindow.document.write("<img src='"+imgString+"'/>");
        mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');
  }
});

    }
```

Comment: I cannot load your examples, but I'm guessing that I've got a similar problem. I think there is an issue with the map tile loading after you zoom or pan.  One funky solution is to change the map type (manually) and then try saving the map.  But it doesn't always work.